# Can't create File in Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, file

Chasing [Google Android Trainings](https://developer.android.com/) I tried to create a File in Internal storage and modify that.

but there is an unknown problem and I can't debug it.

Below I have copied my mainActivity class which contains all code I have written for the pupose, but I really can't debug it!!! I just can see nothing in TextView !!

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
final static String fileName = "myFile.txt";
File file;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initializeFile();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    try {
        tv.setText(readFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}


public void initializeFile(){
    try {
        file = new File(getFilesDir() , fileName);
        if(!file.exists()){
            Log.d("BUG","No Files !!");
        }
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(fileName , MODE_PRIVATE);
        out.write("My text".getBytes());
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String readFile() throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        Log.d("BUG","NO File(reading)");
    }
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        s += scan.nextLine();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: you never call out.close()

Comment: it doesn't matter that much, I have used in original code.

Comment: then you should post the original code,

Comment: I have fixed it, this is the ORIGINAL one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `setContentView(R.layout.main)` before you try to obtain TextView tv. Elsewhere there is NPE, cause you main view is not inflated and there is no any view with id R.id.text_view. Everything else works fine.

Comment: I really don't believe my eyes!!! I've tried that for more than 20 times, but now it's OK!!! Thank you.